# Audio over radio in neighbourhood, possible and legal?

Tags: audio, radio

In my neighbourhood there are three five-year-old friends (including my kid) that live within a radius of 450m of each other.

I had an idea that it would be fun if they could have some kind of push-to-talk walkie-talkie-like installation that would enable them to talk to each other from their rooms.

Do you think this would be

1. Possible?
2. Legal?

What would be the best way to achieve this? I thought about some kind of CB based radio, like on the ~27Mhz band, but I am not sure. Are there any ideas out there?

I am an embedded software engineer, I know some KiCAD, I have done simple boards, but not much with radio outside some LoRa break-out boards. I have not done much with analog radio, but it would be fun to learn.

If you where to do a project like above, what approach would you take?

Comment: What??? The children don’t have mobile devices?  As for legality, it depends on where in the world you are.

Comment: Given that you're a software engineer, what about an internet-based solution? They probably all have WiFi at home. An ESP32, a speaker, a microphone and a TCP connection... Off you go. 450 meters is most likely too much for anything you don't need a license for (i.e. 433MHz serial communication)

Comment: Actual off the shelf walkie talkies (via FRS or ISM bands, in the US at least...) Or: do they have line of sight? If you specifically want an analog electronics project, maybe try an optical link in the visible band  ie LED / photodiode via  telescope...

Comment: Depending on which country you live in a [personal radio service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_radio_service) may be a legal option for you. Alternatively you could set up a private group on an app like [Zello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zello) that offers PTT operation over tablets or smartphones.

Comment: Get walkie talkie radios

Comment: Ordinary licence-free walkie talkies should be able to do more than that distance, if you buy serious ones, not kids' toys.  In Europe, the PMR446 standard radios can do about 3 to 5km with clear line-of-sight.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely possible,
It is completely legal if you pick the right power and frequency.
It might be easiest to simply use something like the Motorola radios that were so common in the early 2000s with encrypted paired devices.  Alternatively, getting some used Samsung TabA tablets for $20 each and let them talk via android's version of FaceTime.